# Erlang xmerl_sax_parser throwing error

Tags: xml, parsing, erlang

I am parsing through a pretty large file with xmerl_sax_parser:file() and get an exception half-way through.

```
exception throw: {'EXIT',{undef,[{xmerl_sax_parser_utf8,cf,
                                                       [<<"Ä">>,
                                                        {xmerl_sax_parser_state}]}]}}
```

I have looked at the data and it doesn't not contain any weird chars and if it did how can I handle it. The documentation does not tell me anything.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
run(FileName) ->
{ok, Xml, _Rest} =
   xmerl_sax_parser:file(FileName,  [{event_fun, fun event/3},
                                      {event_state, {[], ""}},
                                    {encoding, utf8},
                                    {file_type, normal},
                                    skip_external_dtd]),
Xml.

event(_Ev = {startElement, _, "product", _, _}, _Loc, _State = {Xml, _}) ->
{[[]|Xml], ""};
event(_Event = {characters, Chars}, _Location, _State = {Quotes, _}) ->
{Quotes, Chars};
event(_Ev = {endElement,_,"stock",_},_L,_State = {[Data|Rest],Chars}) ->
           Element = list_to_atom("name"),
           Updated = [{Element, Chars}|Data],
           {[Updated|Rest], undefined};
event(_Ev = {endElement,_,"date",_},_L,_State = {[Data|Rest],Chars}) ->
           Element = list_to_atom("brand"),
           Updated = [{Element, Chars}|Data],
           {[Updated|Rest], undefined};
event(_Ev = {endElement,_,"open",_},_L,_State = {[Data|Rest],Chars}) ->
           Element = list_to_atom("price"),
           Updated = [{Element, Chars}|Data],
           {[Updated|Rest], undefined};
event(_Ev = {endElement,_,"low",_},_L,_State = {[Data|Rest],Chars}) ->
           Element = list_to_atom("url"),
           Updated = [{Element, Chars}|Data],
           {[Updated|Rest], undefined};
event(_Ev = {endElement,_,"stats",_},_L,_State = {[Data|Rest],Chars}) ->
           Element = list_to_atom("category"),
           Updated = [{Element, Chars}|Data],
           {[Updated|Rest], undefined};
event(_Event, _Location, State) ->
State.
```

Any thoughts of how to fix or handle properly?

Comment: That's strange; something is trying to call `xmerl_sax_parser_utf8:cf/2` but my version only has `cf/3`, `cf/4` and `cf/5`... Which Erlang release is this?

Answer (score 0):

**THIS part is wrong, sorry :o(**

> May be the file you are reading is not encoded in utf8. I checked in
>   the extended ASCII table, the weird char being displayed has the value
>   142 (2#10001110) which is not a valid utf8 code:

[image: UTF8 encoding - from wikipedia]

according to this table, it is a continuation code. So you could  inspect your input file with an hex editor looking for the byte 142 (16#8E).

**EDIT:** I realize that I don't know which character encoding is used to print the exception message. I made some test in a console, and I got this:

```
(exec@WXFRB1824L)1> L = <<"Ä">>.
<<"Ä">>
(exec@WXFRB1824L)2> size(L).  
1
(exec@WXFRB1824L)3> <<L1:4,L2:4>> = L.
<<"Ä">>
(exec@WXFRB1824L)4> L1.
12
(exec@WXFRB1824L)5> L2.
4
(exec@WXFRB1824L)6> L = <<2#11000100>>.
<<"Ä">>
(exec@WXFRB1824L)7> 2#11000100.
196
```

This is not printed as UTF8 but ASCII (I made a mistake, I cannot find where I got this value of 142...)
This changes things, because 196 is a valid UT8 first byte for a 2 bytes data according to the following table:
[image]

Comment: It looks like a Ä however it is a Ã.

Answer (score 0):

I found the `SAX` parser for  [`erlsom`](http://erlsom.sourceforge.net/erlsom.htm#sax_mode)  library much very easy to use. I recommend it's use as compared to xmerl.